# Grafana (loki-stack) datasource provision issue with file permissions

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, rancher, grafana-loki

We are installing a Grafana Loki stack via Helm charts.

```
helm -n loki-stack upgrade --install loki-stack grafana/loki-stack --values values-loki-stack-2.0-dev.yaml
```

We use Loki version 2.8.4 and Grafana version 10.1.1. We are getting the following error in the pod `loki-stack-grafana` and container `grafana-sc-datasources`.

```json
{"time": "2023-09-06T12:38:49.126208+00:00", "level": "ERROR", "msg": "Error when updating from $datasources.yaml into $/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources: $[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml'"}
```

This is the config of `$datasources.yaml`:

```yaml
grafana:
  datasources:
    datasources.yaml:
      apiVersion: 1
      datasources:
        - name: LokiProm
          type: prometheus
          orgId: 1
          access: proxy
          url: http://loki-stack:3100/loki
          jsonData:
            timeout: 500
```

**The result is that we do not see any data in our Grafana dashboards.**

The `datasources.yaml` file's permission is set to `root:472` while all the other files have user & group `472`.

The user `472` apparently does not exist at all (e.g. looked it up with `tail /etc/passwd`).

I tried to change the file permissions of the file via Rancher SSH connect but unfortunately this was not possible due to permissions too. Also the connection fails every other second.

Answer (score 0):

The mention of user ID 472 not existing in the `/etc/passwd` file suggests a potential issue with the file ownership.

Just make sure what user is running Grafana. Once you identify the user, assign the same user to the datasources.yaml. Ensure that it has appropriate read permissions for Grafana to access it. If I assume the user is 'grafana' which is always a default user.

```
sudo chown grafana:grafana /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml
sudo chmod 644 /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml
```

Restart the Grafana and observe the logs.

Comment: If the file is owned by Grafana, there is no need to make it world readable - including the contained "credentials".